# Why is my ProgressBar variable is considered as null? this is in a fragment by the way

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, progress-bar

I was wondering why the value of progressBarLoading is null.

This was the java code for the fragment:

```
public ProgressBar progressBarLoading;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_one, container, false);
    progressBarLoading = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading);
    progressBarLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return view;
}
```

And this is for the XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/primary">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newReleases"
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="282dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarLoading"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="216dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookCover"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="216dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is the Error in Question:

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference**

Comment: because you never instantiate it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have inflated a wrong layout.

if "R.layout.home_fragment_one" in below code is wrong you will get nullPointerException for "progressBarLoading".

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment_one, container, false);
```